# OpenAM user account lock : set multiple attribute

Tags: openam

OpenAM version : 11.0.0
OpenAM server : apache tomcat

We have a requirement to set multiple attribite when a user locks.
By defult its setting inetstatus attribute value.
but we need to some value to our custom attribute also when a user locks.

How can we achieve this ?

Thanks

Abhilash KP

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways that we can configure account lockout and related activities. Either in the OpenAM or in the backend Directory server (Using the password policy). Please have a look on the below link to get some more information

http://idmdude.com/2014/04/22/understanding-openam-and-opendj-account-lockout-behaviors/

Comment: Thanks For your comment, but for our requirement we need to set customized values to 2 attributes based on the user lock.Is there any way to catch the lock/unlock event. As per our requirement we need to call a webservice at the time of user lock and unlock.

Comment: I am not sure how to set more than one attribute on account lock/unlock. There is an option in  OpenDJ (Directory Server) to send notification mail on account lock/unlock. This cand be done using the dsconfig  set-account-status-notification-handler-prop command. But in your case you need to invoke webservice. So dont think that will help